# symfony2 ajax post becomes get when using annotation for routing

Tags: php, ajax, symfony

I recently switched the routing on my symfony2 bundle to use inline annotations in the controller rather than a routing.yml file.  Afterwards, ajax post requests started coming through with no parameters.  I looked into it and noticed that the logs were showing the post requests as [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET.  Taking off the annotated route turned the request to a post.  The thing was working perfectly before I switched the routing.

here's the controller and route

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

  /**
   * @Route("/emailShare/", name="emailShare")
   * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
   */
  public function indexAction()
```

and the jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url: '/v2/social/emailShare',
```

If I use curl to post to the same url, it shows up in the logs as a post.

```
curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://mysite.com/v2/social/emailShare/
```

Comment: if anyone can verify that they are experiencing the same behavior, that would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

My annotation-based routes perform Ajax calls via POST without a problem.  There are a couple of differences from your setup:  I'm not using the @Method annotation in the controller at all, and (FWIW) my  jQuery Ajax method value is in all caps.  For example:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
   {
    /**
     *
     * @Route("/", name="emailShare")
     */
    public function indexAction()
```

And the jQuery (I'm using Twig to set the path):

```
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '{{path("emailShare")}}',
```

And the relevant routing.yml lines:

```
AcmeDemoBundle:
resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /
```

Comment: I only added the @Method and the lowercase post to test this issue, so I don't think those are it.  what do your main routing file (/symfony/app/config/routing.yml) annotation definitions look like?

Comment: The only relevant lines in the routing.yml file are those that direct the router to look at annotations to define paths: `AcmeDemoBundle:
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /`

Comment: yep, mine look exactly the same.  This is a strange one